# Using volley library inside a library

Tags: android, jar, android-volley

I want to make a library to reduce my duplicate network works on every android projects or even give my jar to some other developers to using my methods for network communications.

So i build this:

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Request.Priority;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;

public class RequestResp {
    private final static String WEB_SERVICE_URL = "http://blabla/api";
    private final Priority priorityImmediatelly = Priority.IMMEDIATE;
    private final Priority priorityHigh = Priority.HIGH;
    private final Priority priorityNORMAL = Priority.NORMAL;
    private String tag_req_default = "tag_req_default";
    VolleyCustomRequest mVolleyCustomReq;
    DefaultRetryPolicy drp = new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    public /*JSONObject*/ void sendParamsAsHighPriority(Map<String, String> params) {

        mVolleyCustomReq = new VolleyCustomRequest(Method.POST,
                WEB_SERVICE_URL, params, new Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                        }
                    }
                }, new ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(tag_req_default, error.getMessage());
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            public Priority getPriority() {
                return priorityHigh;
            }

        };
        mVolleyCustomReq.setRetryPolicy(drp);
        VolleyController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(mVolleyCustomReq,
                tag_req_default);
/*return response; ?!?!?*/
    }
}
```

But how to return response?! Cause if server was busy or down or something that make response a little late, developers in their applications get null!(i guess).

How to make a such this?! Build a jar library that has a class that has a method that give parameters and send it on specific URL, with volley library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Interface like

```
public interface OntaskCompleted {

    public void onSuccess(JSONObject response);
    public void onError(String message);
}
```

Now Your activity should implement this interface and you have to override these method.

Now in you Volley class do this.

```
 if (response != null) {
 ontaskCompleted.onSuccess(JSONObject);
                        }
```

and

```
 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(tag_req_default, error.getMessage());
                        ontaskCompleted.onError( error.getMessage());
                                                }
```

Now your activity will get the result of error or success.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: If developers (use my jar in their apps) call sendParamsAsHighPriority method twice, the response in onSuccess is for which one and developer how to know that?!

Comment: If you are running it asynchronously.Then it will be like first come first serve.It means the first response will be the response of the first api call.